# Overloading method with parameters similar to overloading constructors

Tags: java

I know about overloading constructors with the "this" word, but I was wondering if it was possible to overload methods in a similar manner. I was hoping to do this:

```
public static int ArrayIndex(int[] array) {
    this(array, 0, array.length);
}

public static int ArrayIndex(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    //code
}
```

where the first method would call the second method with the "default parameters". Is this possible?

Comment: `return ArrayIndex(array, 0, array.length);`

Comment: It’s simple to just try it, isn’t it? And when you do you find that it’s not possible. The ‘this()’ syntax is only for invoking constructors

Answer (score -1):

You could just return calling another method: 
Example

```
public int CalculateSqr(int number, sqr){
    return Math.pow(number,sqr);
}
public int CalculateSqr(int number){
    return CalculateSqr(number,2);
}
```